# Convert mathematica graph to txt

Tags: plotting

I can convert the plotted graph to txt format using the mathematicada plot command with the help of the code below. However, when I use the ContourPlot command, I cannot do the same.

```
dd = 0.832606; ee = -1.87416; ff = 0.396505;

xxx = ContourPlot[dd i^2 + ee i l + ff l^2 - 0.55^2 == 0, {i, -10, 10}, {l, -10, 10}]

multidat = Cases[First@xxx, Line[data_] :> data, -4];
 
Export["file" <> IntegerString[#2] <> ".txt", #, "Table"]& ~ MapIndexed ~ multidat
```

Comment: @cocomoco What's your goal, you don't want to use info strorded in `GraphicsComplex`?

Comment: @Ulrich Neumann I want to get all the values in the chart as txt and plot them in excel.

Answer (score 1):

If you 're only interested in the point values of `xxx`

```
points = xxx[[1]][[1, 1]]
```

creates the list of points used by `GraphicsComplex`.

If you want to evaluate the line-points for further use try

```
index = Cases[First@xxx, Line[data_] :> data, -1] ;
linepoints=Map[points[[#]]&,index]
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I want to export all values to txt file, not just one

Comment: `points`contains a list of all points used.

Comment: I was able to export to txt file automatically in Plot command. I wanted to know if there is a way to do the same in the Contourplot command.

Comment: Please show your code for the `Plot`-version

Comment: `Plot` creates a `Graphics`-object whereas `ContourPlot` creates a `GraphicsComplex`!

Comment: In the plot, I solved it for a single variable in the equation and exported it to txt. As far as I understand, since there are two variables in the equation I shared, I will not be able to perform the same transfer process automatically.

Comment: My answer shows the solution for different line-objects!

Comment: For a `Graphics`-object the command `Cases[..., Line[p_] :> p, -1]` gives the list of linepoints